# Using the definition of differentiability in normed spaces, show that the function is differentiable at $(1,-1)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces

> Using the definition of differentiability in normed spaces, show that
>    the function $$f(x,y) = (2x^2+xy+1,xy,x^2+y^2) ~~\text{ is
>  differentiable at } (1,-1)$$

As usual, I list our $$\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)}\dfrac{||f(1+h,-1+k)-f(1,-1)-f^{'}(1,-1)\begin{pmatrix}h\\k\end{pmatrix}||}{||\begin{pmatrix}h\\k\end{pmatrix}||}$$

and try to show it is $0$. I slowly deduced to this step $$\dfrac{|h||2h+k|+|h||k|+(h^2+k^2)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

I cannot get to the next step where my professor showed the above is lesser or equals to $$(2|h|+|k|)+|k|+\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$$

Is there any techniques that I miss?

Comment: Use $|h|\leq\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$ and $|2h+k|\leq|2h|+|k|$.

Comment: I changed "metric space" to "normed space" to conform to common definitions of these terms. [Metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space), [Normed space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A systematic way to do this is to introduce $r=\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$ and use the inequalities $|h|\le r$, $|k|\le r$. Then 
$$
\dfrac{|h||2h+k|+|h||k|+(h^2+k^2)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} 
\le 
\dfrac{r(2r+r) + r^2 +r^2 }{r} = 5r
$$
which obviously tends to zero as $r\to 0$.